# videowriter crashes when run using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller, windows-10-desktop

For the past several weeks I have been using videowriter.write() and it has been working fine. I needed to give the program to several coworkers that have random python installations so I packaged it up in pyinstaller, which I have used successfully on other projects.

Almost everything seems to be working fine when run under pyinstaller, I can read images, capture images from the camera, show them on the screen, and write out individual images. The problem is that when I use videowriter.write() somewhere down in the bowels of the code it crashes, complaining that the images have the incorrect size. This only happens when running under pyinstaller, not when running it directly from python.

Below is a portion of the code that I extracted with a generated test image.  A coworker tried to run the same example, using his copy of opencv, python, and pyinstaller and his executable seems to work. I spent the last several days trying to duplicate that setup but I don't get the same results. I have completely removed python 3 (I have a copy of 2.7 that is specifically for other tests), cleared the pip cache, cleared environment variables, and made sure all the python directories were removed prior to re-installation. I have tried python back to 3.7, different versions of opencv 4.1 through current, and all behave the same way. I have also tried using a virtual environment and setting up the core python sitting in Program Files.

The current version of opencv_videoio_ffmpeg is: opencv_videoio_ffmpeg420_64.dll.
The version that my coworker used successfully is opencv_ffmpeg410_64.dll

While it doesn't seem to make much difference, the command I have been using to build the executable is:

```
pyinstaller videowriter_test.py --onefile
```

I have also tried it without the --onefile option, it works the same but its a little harder to find the executable.

The python installation has the following installed: opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python, imutils, pynput, keyboard, virtualenv, pyinstaller. These were all installed using pip.

pyinstaller stats:

```
129 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6 
129 INFO: Python: 3.7.7 
131 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 
133 INFO: wrote C:\Users\tbray\Desktop\MyProjects\Python3\Play\videowriter\videowriter_test.spec
137 INFO: UPX is not available. 139 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
```

The test code:

```
import traceback
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
# the rest are just there to make sure pyinstaller includes the same modules
# as my regular code
import copy
import platform
import pathlib
import select
import argparse
import warnings
import datetime
import json
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = 640
    h = 480
    currentVideoLogFilename = "test.avi"
    print(os.getenv('temppath'))
    try:
        print("Attempting to open Video Log:", currentVideoLogFilename)
        video_log_file = cv2.VideoWriter(currentVideoLogFilename,
                    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30, (w, h),True)
        print("Open Success")
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

    print("Test Image Shape:", w, h)
    image = np.zeros((w, h, 3))
    try:
        video_log_file.write(image)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    print("Completed")
    video_log_file.release()
    print("file closed/released")
    sys.exit(0)
```

If I run the using idle or pyCharm, I get this result:

```
================== RESTART: C:\Users\tbray\Desktop\MyProjects\Python3\Play\videowriter\videowriter_test.py ==================
None
Attempting to open Video Log: test.avi
Open Success
Test Image Shape: 640 480
Completed
file closed/released
>>>
```

if I run it from the virtual environment I get:

```
C:\Users\tbray\Desktop\MyProjects\Python3\Play\videowriter\dist>videowriter_test.exe
None
Attempting to open Video Log: test.avi
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (415) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): test.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'


Open Success
Test Image Shape: 640 480
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videowriter_test.py", line 39, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:476: error: (-215:Assertion failed) imgWidth == frameWidth && imgHeight == frameHeight && channels == 3 in function 'cv::mjpeg::MotionJpegWriter::write'

Completed
file closed/released
```

One interesting note is what I assume is the temp directory that is referenced in the first error message. I have no idea where the directory comes from and what happens to it, it is missing when I go looking for it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just ran it under nuitka and it failed with the same error. Very interesting.

Comment: I just installed it on my home laptop. I don't think python has ever been installed on this computer. It also fails at the same point. I tried changing the build line to include either add-data or add-binary for the "..cv2\C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg420_64.dll";, option.

Comment: I was looking through OpenCV source and the CV_Assert is just this:
#define CV_Assert( expr ) do { if(!!(expr)) ; else cv::error( cv::Error::StsAssert, #expr, CV_Func, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); } while(0)